# Mail crashes permanently - can't open it anymore

Tags: mail.app, email, crash

I have a question and need a bit of help.
I do have my complete mails on my Mac since 2012. Now today Apple Mail crashes when I opened it. I looked up where the files are and I do have more then 105 GB of mails in the Library.
Now - YES - I could delete all folders - which would take away all my infos from the past. 
I can't get in and archive or do anything. 
Is there any fix to that or do I need to start new ??

Answer (score 0):

First, try rebuilding your Mails' Envelope Index..

To do this:

1. log into your user
2. make sure Mail is NOT running.
3. pull down "Go", click (near the bottom item) "Go to Folder", and insert this in the window:  ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/
4. Look for:  Envelope Index
5. Delete it (drag to trash).. DO NOT EMPTY TRASH YET...
6. restart Mail.  It will tell you that it needs to rebuild the account.. this could take seconds, minutes, or hours..... do not interrupt it...

This is the fastest/best way to rebuild your Mail account...

Comment: Note that El Capitan Mail is now in V3.